# Copy & Paste a whole .txt file into Excel in VB.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

Probably a stupid question, and in VBA I would do it manually & create a Macro, but I don't know how to do that in VB.net, if there is a way then just letting me know that would be great !!!

Anyway, what I want to do in VB.net is the equivalent of manually Selecting a whole .TXT file & Pasting it into the first Cell of an Excel Worksheet ... The file handling I can do, I just don't know the best way to go about the copy & paste.

For example, I guess that I could read the entire .TXT file & write it line-by-line into the Clipboard & then Paste the Clipboard into the Excel file, but I would imagine that's pretty inefficient !!!

Comment: Do you want to put the 'WHOLE' txt file inside a single cell? Or do you want to put a 'line' from the txt file inside a row (dividing the line in 'cells' with some separator character?

Comment: The text file has Tabs, it's actually a League Table, so each piece of data should go into its own cell ...

Comment: Could you give an example of some lines in your input file? All lines have the same number of `fields` separated by tabs?

Comment: Hmmm, how to make this readable ?!?

`...TEAM NAME... PL W D L F A Dif Pts
1  MALLOREAN UTD        3  3  0  0   15 1    14  9
2  KVH FOXES            4  2  2  0   9  5    4  8
3  NORWEGIAN REDS       4  2  1  1   13 9    4  7`

Any good ?

Comment: ...TEAM NAME... PL W D L F A Dif Pts

Comment: 1  MALLOREAN UTD        3  3  0  0   15 1    14  9

Comment: 2  KVH FOXES            4  2  2  0   9  5    4  8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bit complicated, Steve, though there may be more to it than I understand, but I used the following which seems to work fine ...

```
    myNewTable = myFolder + "League Table S" + mySession + ".xlsx"

    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oRow As Int16 = 0

    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    'Read input .txt file line-by-line, Copy to Clipboard & Paste to Excel

    Using rdr As New System.IO.StreamReader(myNewTableTemp)
        Do While rdr.Peek() >= 0
            Dim InputLine As String = rdr.ReadLine
            oRow = oRow + 1
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(InputLine)
            oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" + oRow.ToString).Select()
            oBook.Worksheets(1).Paste()
        Loop
        rdr.Close()
    End Using

    oBook.SaveAs(myNewTable)
    oBook = Nothing
    oExcel.Quit()
    oExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you could prepare an empty excel file with just one worksheet named 'LEAGUE'.
In this sheet you have defined, in the first row, the following values (each for every cell)

> TEAMNAME PL W D L F A Dif Pts

now you could write a pseudo code like this, (need some tests):

```
Dim results() = File.ReadAllLines("yourfile.txt")

Dim connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                       "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;" + 
                       "HDR=YES;IMEX=0'", "yourexcelfile.xlsx")

Using cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    cn.Open();
    Dim sqlCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [LEAGUE$] " + 
                         "(TEAMNAME,PL,W,D,L,F,A,Dif,Pts)" +
                         "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", cn)

    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@played", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@win", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deu", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@los", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dif", string.Empty)
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pts", string.Empty)

    For Each line in results
        Dim cells() = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@team").Value = cells(0)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@played").Value = cells(1)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@win").Value = cells(2)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@deu").Value = cells(3)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@los").Value = cells(4)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@f").Value = cells(5)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@a").Value = cells(6)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@dif").Value = cells(7)
        sqlCommand.Parameters("@pts").Value = cells(8)
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Using
```